# URL encoding different between http and https in Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, url, get, urlencode

I have a form that posts an email address via GET. It's just a text box for an email address and a submit button. There's an encoding problem in Firefox. For example, entering 'test@test.com' in https:// in Firefox will post:

`myurl.com/signup/?email=test%2540test.com`

Entering that in IE will post:

`myurl.com/signup/?email=test%40test.com`

Also, entering that in Firefox from http:// will post:

`myurl.com/signup/?email=test%40test.com`

Does anyone know why Firefox also encoded the % to %25 in https mode?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  Do you have a page showing the problem?  Are you running any interesting url-rewriting extensions?

Comment: It only happens when posting from the https part of our site to the http part of it. If we post to http://myrul.com, we get the correct encoding (test%40test.com). However, we get a security warning because we're posting to an unsecure page from a secure page. If we post to https://myurl.com, we get the problem with (test%2540test.com).

Comment: ok, but none of that answers the questions I asked....